# how do I bring the text into the middle in this featurette shown in the picture?

Tags: html, css

[featurette in Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je4kV.png)

Hi, how do I make my text shift down to the middle as shown in the picture. I try to find everything on center tag but to no avail, hope someone can enlighten me, thanks!

```html
  <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Some great placeholder content for the first featurette here. Imagine some exciting prose here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img insert link>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you share with us a reproductible sample with your html and your css ?

Comment: With a minimalistic search you would've easily found an answer for your question. for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: ah the word "vertically center" escape me, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)